# Need help understand this theorem of decision trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, decision-trees

A version of the game of Nim is used to illustrate the minmax strategy in Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 11 p. 768.  I understand the `+1` and `-1` labels here.  However, why is there not a `[121]` node at the second level?  (question 1)

[image: n1]

However, I had trouble understand this part (question 2):

[image: n2]

Say if I start from the rightmost node `[21]` in the second level.  The first player will seek to win, and thus will choose one of the two `+1` options in the level below.  The second player will be forced to pick up the last stone and thus lose.  So shouldn't the value of this node `[21]` be `+1` instead?

Say if I start from the rightmost node `[1]` of the third level, the first player must pick up the only stone there is.  So shouldn't the value of this node be `-1` in this case?

I am so confused by the stated Theorem 3.  Please help.

Comment: You ask why there isn't a `121` node?  What is the difference between having taken a single stone from the first pile that has two stones versus having taken a single stone from the second pile that has two stones?  Hardly anything... in both cases you are left with one pile with two stones, and two piles with one stone each.  Why then should we bother writing them as separate cases?

Comment: I see!  Can you help me with the other question?

Comment: "*Say if I start from the right most node...*"  For this tree, the game began at the root node of `221`.  Having traveled from that root node to `21` the first player took his turn to empty one of the piles of two stones.  It is now the second player's turn.  The second player now has the choice as to which play to make and will choose to empty the remaining pile of two stones which leaves just a single pile with a single stone in it for the first player's turn.  The first player has no legal moves remaining and thus loses.  It is the second players choice where to continue from `21`.

Comment: @JMoravitz, theorem 3 states that: `The value of a vertex of a game tree tells us the payoff to the first player if both players follow the minmax strategy and play starts from the position represented by this vertex.`  I am trying to understand it, and the numbering of the second picture.

Comment: Try rewording it to "*...and play* **continues** *from the position represented by this vertex.*"  You seem to have taken the phrase "*starts from*" to imply that the first player is the next to act when that is not necessarily the case.  Vertices pictured as squares in the image are ones where the first player is next to act.  Vertices pictured as circles in the image are ones where the *second* player is next to act.

Comment: If reworded as such, everything makes sense.  The original wording clearly tells me that the game restarts (by their wording `...play starts from [this vertex].`) at any chosen vertex.  That also leads to all leaves having value of `-1`.  So would you say that the wording of the book is terribly misleading?

Comment: "Terribly misleading?"  No.  I wouldn't.  It was clear to me that "*starts from this vertex*" was in reference to "*starts from this game position*" and that game positions include not only information as to how many stones are left in which piles but also *whose turn it is*.  It is unfortunate that you got confused by it, which is why I suggested the rewording that I had to help clarify things, but from context it should have been clear the intention.

Comment: @JMoravitz, the word `start` suggests a `restart` to me.  I cannot understand it as `continue`, and will never figure it out without your help.

Answer (score 1):

As per @JMoravitz's explanation in the comment, theorem 3 should be understood as:

The value of a vertex of a game tree tells us the payoff to the first player if both players follow the minmax strategy and play **continues** from the position represented by this vertex.

This is supported by the wording of the inductive step of the theorem's proof, which suggests that a **continuation** of the game and not a **reset**.  A continuation retains the players' turns.

[image: n3]

If **starts** entails maintaining the players' turns, then everything is fine.  I am still bothered by the use of **starts** here, and feel that it is rather misleading in this context.